# same CA, same CN

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Can you order several certs from the same CA, in which only the DN differs, but the CN is the same?

Will they accept a second request for the same CN or maybe then put the first cert on the revocation list automatically?

Purpose of the question: We need a few certs for Prod, Test and Dev, which need to be certs from an official CA, and our guys want to use the same CN and only make one of the OUs different.

Comment: This is essentially answered by [Is it OK to create a new SSL certificate before the old one expires?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95964/is-it-ok-to-create-a-new-ssl-certificate-before-the-old-one-expires). Yes, you can have in general multiple certificates with the same CN (although note the CN does not matter much today, use subject alternative names) from the same CA which are valid at the same time. If a particular CA puts restrictions on this - I don't know. But you can do this for example with LetsEncrypt.